# Giving user a way to add to home screen without user engagement with PWA

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am aware that chrome can prompt alert to add the icon to home screen when PWA requirement are met as listed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria). One of the requirement is user interaction.

> the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds

However, I would like to give user option to do so **without** any prior engagement. As an example, I would like to give a link in promotional email, which will take user to the app like usual, but also open the prompt to add icon to home page.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think that 30-second rule is currently enforced in chrome (Android). Here is a tester I use for Add to Home screen with different browsers. The custom button shows for me as soon as the page is loaded.  https://a2hs.glitch.me/ . You can add a button to A2HS

Comment: Note: There is also a "temporary" install prompt on Chrome Android that shows.